# Stack around the variable 'Yarray' was corrupted

Tags: c++, arrays, exception, stack

When I declare an array to store the Y values of each coordinate, define its values then use each of the element values to send into a rounding function, i obtain the error  'Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'Yarray; was corrupted. The output is mostly what is expected although i'm wondering why this is happening and if i can mitigate it, cheers.

```
void EquationElement::getPolynomial(int * values)   
{

//Takes in coefficients to calculate Y values for a polynomial//

    double size = 40; 
    double step = 1;



    int Yarray[40];




    int third = *values;
    int second = *(values + 1);
    int first = *(values + 2);
    int constant = *(values + 3);







    double x, Yvalue;



    for (int i = 0; i < size + size + 1; ++i) {
        x = (i - (size));
        x = x * step;


        double Y = (third *(x*x*x)) + (second *(x*x)) + (first * (x)) 



        Yvalue = Y / step;

        Yarray[i] = int(round(Yvalue));  //<-MAIN ISSUE HERE?//

        cout << Yarray[i] << endl;  



    }




}



double EquationElement::round(double number)
{



    return number < 0.0 ? ceil(number - 0.5) : floor(number + 0.5);

// if n<0 then ceil(n-0.5) else if >0 floor(n+0.5) ceil to round up floor to round down
}
```

Comment: Why do you have `size + size + 1` as the upper bound of the loop? That puts `i` up to 81, but `Yarray` has only 40 elements.

Comment: Just noticed your comment. This is why the error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

```
// values could be null, you should check that
// if instead of int* values, you took std::vector<int>& values
// You know besides the values, the quantity of them
void EquationElement::getPolynomial(const int* values)
{
    //Takes in coefficients to calculate Y values for a polynomial//
    static const int size = 40; // No reason for size to be double
    static const int step = 1; // No reason for step to be double

    int Yarray[2*size+1]{}; // 40 will not do {} makes them initialized to zero with C++11 onwards

    int third = values[0];
    int second = values[1]; // avoid pointer arithmetic
    int first = values[2]; // [] will work with std::vector and is clearer
    int constant = values[3]; // Values should point at least to 4 numbers; responsability goes to caller

    for (int i = 0; i < 2*size + 1; ++i) {
        double x = (i - (size)) * step; // x goes from -40 to 40

        double Y = (third *(x*x*x)) + (second *(x*x)) + (first * (x)) + constant;
        // Seems unnatural that x^1 is values and x^3 is values+2, being constant at values+3
        double Yvalue= Y / step; // as x and Yvalue will not be used outside the loop, no need to declare them there

        Yarray[i] = int(round(Yvalue));  //<-MAIN ISSUE HERE?//
        // Yep, big issue, i goes from 0 to size*2; you need size+size+1 elements

        cout << Yarray[i] << endl;  
    }
}
```

Instead of

```
void EquationElement::getPolynomial(const int* values)
```

You could also declare

```
void EquationElement::getPolynomial(const int (&values)[4])
```

Which means that now you need to call it with a pointer to 4 elements; no more and no less.

Also, with `std::vector`:

```
void EquationElement::getPolynomial(const std::vector<int>& values)
{
    //Takes in coefficients to calculate Y values for a polynomial//
    static const int size = 40; // No reason for size to be double
    static const int step = 1; // No reason for step to be double

    std::vector<int> Yarray;
    Yarray.reserve(2*size+1); // This is just optimization. Yarran *Can* grow above this limit.

    int third = values[0];
    int second = values[1]; // avoid pointer arithmetic
    int first = values[2]; // [] will work with std::vector and is clearer
    int constant = values[3]; // Values should point at least to 4 numbers; responsability goes to caller

    for (int i = 0; i < 2*size + 1; ++i) {
        double x = (i - (size)) * step; // x goes from -40 to 40

        double Y = (third *(x*x*x)) + (second *(x*x)) + (first * (x)) + constant;
        // Seems unnatural that x^1 is values and x^3 is values+2, being constant at values+3
        double Yvalue= Y / step; // as x and Yvalue will not be used outside the loop, no need to declare them there

        Yarray.push_back(int(round(Yvalue)));
        cout << Yarray.back() << endl;  
    }
}
```